# why I am getting this error while running the jar file on remote machine all permissions are there to access the file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, testng

```
C:\\Users\\0641351\\Desktop\>java -jar CreatePSWithPrivateDuty1.jar
java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:151)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
at TestNgRunner.Poc_Xml_Runner.main(Poc_Xml_Runner.java:15)
\[TestNG\] \[ERROR\] No test suite found. Nothing to run
Usage: \<main class\> \[options\] The XML suite files to run
Options:

>!     -configfailurepolicy

Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)

>!     -d

Output directory

>!     -dataproviderthreadcount

Number of threads to use when running data providers

>!     -excludegroups

Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude

>!     -groups

Comma-separated list of group names to be run

>!     -junit

JUnit mode
Default: false

>!     -listener

List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener or
ISuiteListener

>!     -methods

Comma separated of test methods
Default: \[\]

>!     -methodselectors

List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector

>!     -mixed

Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with
appropriate runner
Default: false

>!     -objectfactory

List of .class files or list of class names implementing
ITestRunnerFactory

>!     -parallel

Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)

>!     -port

The port

>!     -reporter

Extended configuration for custom report listener

>!     -suitename

Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or
source code

>!     -suitethreadpoolsize

Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
Default: 1

>!     -testclass

The list of test classes

>!     -testjar

A jar file containing the tests

>!     -testname

Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source
code

>!     -testnames

The list of test names to run

>!     -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory

The factory used to create tests

>!     -threadcount

Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel

>!     -usedefaultlisteners

Whether to use the default listeners
Default: true

>!     -log, -verbose

Level of verbosity

>!     -xmlpathinjar

The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if -testjar
was specified)[tag:tag-name]
Default: testng.xml
```

I tried chkdsk command

tried with relative and absolute paths for running the xml file inside jar

want to run the jar file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also fix the format of the post. It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to ensure that you have built a jar that contains the test classes. Your post doesn't explain whether that's the case.

Please refer to https://testng.org/#_running_tests_from_within_a_test_jar to see a complete example of how to use TestNG to run tests that are part of a jar.

To instruct TestNG to look for tests in a jar you should be using the `-testjar` command line argument and if you are looking to have TestNG use a specific suite file within the jar you would need to provide the location via the command line argument `-xmlpathinjar`

Below is a sample command:

```
java -jar target/uber-testjar-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
-testjar target/uber-testjar-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar \
-xmlpathinjar suites/suite2.xml
```